# Using window.location when registering a user account in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using this code to register a user:

```
register = event => {
        console.log(this.state.credentials);
        fetch('http://api.herokuapp.com/account/users/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state.credentials)
        }) .then(res => {
            window.location.href = '/'
        })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))
            alert("Invalid information, please reenter your details correctly")
            window.location.href = '/Oko/RegisterUser'
    }
```

It works fine and I can register a user however, I am wanting to change the `window.location.href` to `/` if the user account is registered. If it is not registered and there is an error (`console.log(error)`), I want to change the `window.location.href` to `/Oko/RegisterUser` (which is the webpage they would already be on). 
Currently, when `register` is called, it is sending the user to `/` regardless of whether there is an error or not.
Is there a way to keep the user on the `RegisterUser` page if there is an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A fetch() promise will reject with a TypeError when a network error is encountered or CORS is misconfigured on the server-side [[developer.mozilla.org]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)

you need to use res.ok to check for HTTP errors

```
register = event => {
    console.log(this.state.credentials);
    fetch('http://api.herokuapp.com/account/users/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state.credentials)
    }) .then(res => {
        if(res.ok) {
          window.location.href = '/'
        } else {
            alert("Invalid information, please reenter your details correctly")
            window.location.href = '/Oko/RegisterUser'
        }
    })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your request is always executing the code inside the .then block because fetch doesn't fail if it receives an HTTP error code.

From the MDN docs:

> The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status
>   even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve
>   normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on
>   network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

Like the docs say, you need to check the property ok of the response object in the .then block:

```
register = event => {
    fetch('http://api.herokuapp.com/account/users/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state.credentials)
    }) .then(res => {
        if(res.ok) {
            window.location.href = '/'
        }else{
            alert("Invalid information, please reenter your details correctly")
            window.location.href = '/Oko/RegisterUser'
        }
    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```